# ejabberd incompatiblity with p1_yaml library

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I have installed erlang/OTP 17.1 from source & I have installed ejabberd from GitHub. Both have installed successfully. But when i am starting ejabberd server, i am getting the following error in error.log.

```
2016-01-08 16:13:57.700 [error] <0.100.0> unable to load p1_yaml NIF: {error,{bad_lib,"Library version (2.8) not compatible (with 2.6)."}}

2016-01-08 16:13:57.700 [error] <0.99.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.99.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {{bad_lib,"Library version (2.8) not compatible (with 2.6)."},{p1_yaml_app,start,[normal,[]]}} in application_master:init/4 line 133

2016-01-08 16:13:57.769 [critical] <0.38.0>@ejabberd:exit_or_halt:133 failed to start application 'p1_yaml': {error,
                                        {{bad_lib,
                                          "Library version (2.8) not compatible (with 2.6)."},
                                         {p1_yaml_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}
```

Comment: Which version of libyaml do you have installed on your system ? Did you upgrade it after you have build ejabberd ?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a `p1_yaml.so` file around that was build with a different version of Erlang runtime than the one you are using.

You should rebuild ejabberd (or just `p1_yaml`) with the correct Erlang version.